# CakePHP maintain ID even when changing views

Tags: php, html, cakephp

How do i maintain the passed id of my form to another form? for instance i have `http://192.168.6.253/computers/brands/table/4` which displays all the records from brands belongsTo computers with condition computer_id=4. Now i have add() which directs me to `http://192.168.6.253/computers/brands/add`. 
My problem now is that I want to retain the computer_id=4 so that when i add a new brand it will save it to the Brand.computer_id in DB. So I want something like `http://192.168.6.253/computers/brands/add/4` also.


Here how i call the add() in my view

```
echo $this->Html->link('Add Brands Here', array(
        'controller' => 'brands',
        'action' => 'add'))
);
```

Here how i call my table brand also in my computers view

```
echo $this->Html->link('P',array('action' => '../brands/table', $computer['Computer']['id']));
```

And my brand add() and table() controller

```
public function table($id = null){
            if (!$id) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
            }

            $this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => array('Brand.computer_id' => $id),
            'limit' => 10
            );
            $data = $this->paginate('Brand');
            $this->set('brands', $data);
        }

        public function add() {

            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $this->Brand->create();
                if ($this->Brand->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $this->Html->link('Add Brands Here'
    , array(
      'controller' => 'brands'
      ,  'action' => 'add'
      , 4 // or whatever variable, maybe $computer['Computer']['id'] ?
    )
);
```

... should do the trick.

It's exactly like the snippet you already used to make that other link. `echo $this->Html->link('P',array('action' => '../brands/table', $computer['Computer']['id']));`

The key point to remember in making those numerical "ids" at the end, is to simply add a non-indexed item into the array.  CakePHP will tack 'em on to the end.

Of course, I'll also have to warn you that adding a "4" at the end like that doesn't really make sense from a REST perspective.  Maybe you're better off using named parameters, like this...

```
echo $this->Html->link('Add Brands Here'
    , array(
      'controller' => 'brands'
      ,  'action' => 'add'
      ,  'computer_id' => 4 // or whatever variable, maybe $computer['Computer']['id'] ?
    )
);
```

... or query string params...

```
echo $this->Html->link('Add Brands Here'
    , array(
      'controller' => 'brands'
      ,  'action' => 'add'
      ,  '?' => array('computer_id' => 4) // or whatever variable, maybe $computer['Computer']['id'] ?
    )
);
```

Take a read more in-depth at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: i have used echo `$this->Html->link('Add Brands Here', array(
        'controller' => 'brands',
        'action' => 'add',
        $brand['Brand']['computer_id']
       )
);`. but i always getting `Undefined index: Brand` error :(

Comment: debug() your stuff.  CakePHP's nested arrays can be a little quirky, but they're consistent with the amount of nesting, based on the type of query performed.